# Repeated Branches in TorchScript Model Export

Tags: pytorch, torchscript

I'm trying to export a PyTorch model to TorchScript via scripting and I am stuck. I've created a toy class to showcase the issue:

```py
import torch
from torch import nn


class SadModule(nn.Module):
    """Takes a (*, 2) input and runs it thorugh a linear layer. Can optionally
    use a skip connection. The usage of the skip connection or not is an
    architectural choice.

    """
    def __init__(self, use_skip: bool):
        nn.Module.__init__(self)
        self.use_skip = use_skip
        self.layer = nn.Linear(2, 2)

    def forward(self, x):
        if self.use_skip:
            x_input = x
        x = self.layer(x)
        if self.use_skip:
            x = x + x_input
        return x
```

It basically consists of only a linear layer and an optional skip connection. If I try to script the model using

```py
mod1 = SadModule(False)
scripted_mod1 = torch.jit.script(mod)
```

I get the following error:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-a7ebc7af32c7> in <module>
----> 1 scripted_mod1 = torch.jit.script(mod)

~/Software/miniconda3/envs/pytorch3d/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/jit/_script.py in script(obj, optimize, _frames_up, _rcb)
    895
    896     if isinstance(obj, torch.nn.Module):
--> 897         return torch.jit._recursive.create_script_module(
    898             obj, torch.jit._recursive.infer_methods_to_compile
    899         )

~/Software/miniconda3/envs/pytorch3d/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/jit/_recursive.py in create_script_module(nn_module, stubs_fn, share_types)
    350     check_module_initialized(nn_module)
    351     concrete_type = get_module_concrete_type(nn_module, share_types)
--> 352     return create_script_module_impl(nn_module, concrete_type, stubs_fn)
    353
    354 def create_script_module_impl(nn_module, concrete_type, stubs_fn):

~/Software/miniconda3/envs/pytorch3d/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/jit/_recursive.py in create_script_module_impl(nn_module, concrete_type, stubs_fn)
    408     # Compile methods if necessary
    409     if concrete_type not in concrete_type_store.methods_compiled:
--> 410         create_methods_and_properties_from_stubs(concrete_type, method_stubs, property_stubs)
    411         torch._C._run_emit_module_hook(cpp_module)
    412         concrete_type_store.methods_compiled.add(concrete_type)

~/Software/miniconda3/envs/pytorch3d/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/jit/_recursive.py in create_methods_and_properties_from_stubs(concrete_type, method_stubs, property_stubs)
    302     property_rcbs = [p.resolution_callback for p in property_stubs]
    303
--> 304     concrete_type._create_methods_and_properties(property_defs, property_rcbs, method_defs, method_rcbs, method_defaults)
    305
    306

RuntimeError:

x_input is not defined in the false branch:
  File "<ipython-input-7-d08ed7ff42ec>", line 12
    def forward(self, x):
        if self.use_skip:
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            x_input = x
            ~~~~~~~~~~~ <--- HERE
        x = self.layer(x)
        if self.use_skip:
and was used here:
  File "<ipython-input-7-d08ed7ff42ec>", line 16
        x = self.layer(x)
        if self.use_skip:
            x = x + x_input
                    ~~~~~~~ <--- HERE
        return x
```

So, basically TorchScript isn't able to recognise that for `mod1` the `True` branch of either `if` statement won't ever be used. Moreover, if we create an instance that actually *uses* the skip connection,

```py
mod2 = SadModule(True)
scripted_mod2 = torch.jit.script(mod2)
```

we will get another error:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-b5ca61d8aa73> in <module>
----> 1 scripted_mod2 = torch.jit.script(mod2)

~/Software/miniconda3/envs/pytorch3d/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/jit/_script.py in script(obj, optimize, _frames_up, _rcb)
    895
    896     if isinstance(obj, torch.nn.Module):
--> 897         return torch.jit._recursive.create_script_module(
    898             obj, torch.jit._recursive.infer_methods_to_compile
    899         )

~/Software/miniconda3/envs/pytorch3d/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/jit/_recursive.py in create_script_module(nn_module, stubs_fn, share_types)
    350     check_module_initialized(nn_module)
    351     concrete_type = get_module_concrete_type(nn_module, share_types)
--> 352     return create_script_module_impl(nn_module, concrete_type, stubs_fn)
    353
    354 def create_script_module_impl(nn_module, concrete_type, stubs_fn):

~/Software/miniconda3/envs/pytorch3d/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/jit/_recursive.py in create_script_module_impl(nn_module, concrete_type, stubs_fn)
    408     # Compile methods if necessary
    409     if concrete_type not in concrete_type_store.methods_compiled:
--> 410         create_methods_and_properties_from_stubs(concrete_type, method_stubs, property_stubs)
    411         torch._C._run_emit_module_hook(cpp_module)
    412         concrete_type_store.methods_compiled.add(concrete_type)

~/Software/miniconda3/envs/pytorch3d/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/jit/_recursive.py in create_methods_and_properties_from_stubs(concrete_type, method_stubs, property_stubs)
    302     property_rcbs = [p.resolution_callback for p in property_stubs]
    303
--> 304     concrete_type._create_methods_and_properties(property_defs, property_rcbs, method_defs, method_rcbs, method_defaults)
    305
    306

RuntimeError:

x_input is not defined in the false branch:
  File "<ipython-input-18-ac8b9713c789>", line 17
    def forward(self, x):
        if self.use_skip:
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            x_input = x
            ~~~~~~~~~~~ <--- HERE
        x = self.layer(x)
        if self.use_skip:
and was used here:
  File "<ipython-input-18-ac8b9713c789>", line 21
        x = self.layer(x)
        if self.use_skip:
            x = x + x_input
                    ~~~~~~~ <--- HERE
        return x
```

So in this case TorchScript doesn't understand that both `if`s will always be true and that in fact `x_input` is well defined.

To avoid the issue, I could split the class into two subclasses, as in:

```py
class SadModuleNoSkip(nn.Module):
    """Takes a (*, 2) input and runs it thorugh a linear layer. Can optionally
    use a skip connection. The usage of the skip connection or not is an
    architectural choice.

    """
    def __init__(self):
        nn.Module.__init__(self)
        self.layer = nn.Linear(2, 2)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.layer(x)
        return x

class SadModuleSkip(nn.Module):
    """Takes a (*, 2) input and runs it thorugh a linear layer. Can optionally
    use a skip connection. The usage of the skip connection or not is an
    architectural choice.

    """
    def __init__(self):
        nn.Module.__init__(self)
        self.layer = nn.Linear(2, 2)

    def forward(self, x):
        x_input = x
        x = self.layer(x)
        x = x + x_input
        return x
```

However, I am working on a huge code base and I would have to repeat the process for many classes, which is time consuming and could introduce bugs. Moreover, often the modules I'm working on are huge convolutional nets and the `if`s just control the presence of an additional batch normalization. It seems to me undesirable to have to classes that are identical in 99% of the blocks, save for a single batch norm layer.

Is there a way in which I can help TorchScript with its handling of branches?

**Edit**: added a minimum viable example.

**Update**: doesn't work even if I type hint `use_skip` as constant

```py
from typing import Final

class SadModule(nn.Module):
    use_skip: Final[bool]
    ...
```

Comment: Can you post some real code here so we can copy-paste and try to debug?

Answer (score 1):

I've opened an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/57717). The project maintainers explained that using `Final` is the way to go. Be careful though, because as of today (May 7, 2021) this feature is still in development (abeit in its final stages, see here for the [feature tracker](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/53414)).

Even though it's not yet available in the official releases, it is present in the nightly versions of PyTorch, so you can either install the `pytorch-nighly` builds as [explained in the website](https://pytorch.org) (scroll down to **Install PyTorch**, then choose *Preview (Nightly)*, or wait for the next release.

For anybody reading this answer a few months from now, this feature should be already integrated in the main releases of PyTorch.